How to perform correlation & regression analysis using both 5-point likert scale and "Yes/No/Maybe" questionnaire?
I have collected a data for my thesis to analyze the degree of awareness among the individual taxpayers. For that purpose, i have distributed the questionnaire that contains questions for IV (audit, penalties, socio-demographic factors, etc) based on 5-point likert scale & Yes/No/Maybe question for the DV (degree of awareness of Tax). I am stuck with analyzing the data where both 5-point likert scale & "Yes/No/maybe" scale are used. Any suggestions to further up my data analysis can be helpful.

Ordinal logistic regression is the standard approach for this kind of data. We have many related threads on this topic. This one may be a good place to start:
Ordinal regression: logit, probit, complementary log-log or negative log-log?
Frank Harrell also maintains detailed notes about these models at his website: https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/

Thanks a lot for your insight. I will go through the links you have provided to get the understanding in more details.

One question I have is whether you consider your “Yes/Maybe/No” variable an “ordinal” such that Yes > Maybe > No. I assume that this is the case but my answer is in part contingent on this being the case and not that you considered it nominal variable (i.e., unordered categorical).
If you consider Y/M/N to be ordered, you could:
(a) Conduct a non-parametric correlation (Spearman Rho or Kendall Tau) between your Likert and Y/M/N variable. This is appropriate for the data given your variables that are ordered categories and not interval, and so you known Yes > Maybe > No but not whether the distances between those levels are the same. Pearson correlation assumes your data is interval so it's not appropriate. Non-parametric correlations do not assume interval data, and only require your data be monotonic (e.g., if it goes up, it keeps going up but not necessarily linearly). A couple options would be Spearman Rho or Kendall Tau
cor(Audit, Tax, method="Spearman")

(b) You can estimate an ordinal logistic regression model with one independent variable treated as an ordered factor by orthogonal polynomial contrast coding it and then predicting the other.
df$Tax <- ordered(df$Tax)
df$Audit <- ordered(df$Audit)
library(ordinal)
clm(Tax ~ Audit, data = df)

For a thorough review of ordinal logistic, this recent paper is a good review of the underlying math and how to implement:
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245918823199
